# How to display popup for each url using page action?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need some guide on how to achieve this kind of thing.

The thing I want to do is to use page_action to display popup for specific URLs. What I want to achieve is something like this:

When a user loads url in the browser, an AJAX request is sent to my service to check for the url. If url is found on my service, say I will return some text against it. That text will then be displayed in the popup.

For that I am using `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener` function. The problem with it is that whenever a user opens a new tab, this function is called, it then updates the popup page, removing the message for the previously opened tab.

Any solution?

**Update:** I am pasting my code, could someone please check what could be the problem?

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version" : 2,

    "name" : "Know your cashback for a site!",
    "version" : "1.0",
    "description" : "Find out about the cashback of the visiting website right in your browser",

    "background" : { "scripts" : ["jquery.js","records.js"]},
    "permissions" : [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "tabs" ],    

    "page_action" : {
                    "default_icon"  : "images/icon.png"
                    }
}
```

records.js

```
var result;
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (tab.url !== undefined && changeInfo.status == "complete") {
            $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/chrome_extension/index.php',
            data: "url=" + encodeURIComponent(tab.url),
            type:'GET',
            success: function(resp) {
                    if(resp=="not_found"||resp=="invalid_request") {
                        // do nothing
                    } else {
                        resp = JSON.parse(resp);
                        chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
                        chrome.pageAction.setTitle({
                                                   tabId: tabId,
                                                   title: resp.cashback
                                                   });
                        chrome.pageAction.setPopup({
                                                   tabId: tabId,
                                                   popup: "popup.htm"
                                                   });
                        window.result = resp;
                        //alert('update successful');
                    }               
                }
            });
    }
};

// Listen for any changes to the URL of any tab.
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);
```

popup.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<span id="request"></span>
<a href="#" id="ref_link"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
var BGPage = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
if(typeof BGPage.result !== undefined) {
document.getElementById('request').innerHTML = BGPage.result.cashback;
document.getElementById('ref_link').href = BGPage.result.store;
}

$('a#ref_link').on('click', function(e) {
    var href = e.currentTarget.href;
    chrome.tabs.query({active:true}, function (tab){
        chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: href});
    });
});
```

Comment: Restrict the page action to specific tabs by passing the tabId to [`chrome.pageAction.setPopup`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction.html#method-setPopup), `show`, etc.

Comment: i have records.js file set as my background script. In this script I use chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener function. After this function is called, i tried to use chrome.pageAction.setPopup as per your suggestion. It does create popup for all urls but then again, whenever new tab is created, it flushes the record for the other opened tabs. :( Any help?  One more thing, I also use chrome.pageAction.setTitle, the value for this thing is never ruined for all opened tabs. Why is it that the popup value is gone?

Comment: Hi @RobW, I've updated the question. Please have a look. Thank you

Comment: Why did you load the same scripts in the background and the popup? Read the documentation for [`chrome.pageAction`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction.html) and [background pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) to improve your knowledge on this topic. Second, what's the intended result of `$('a#ref_link')`? I don't see `<a id="ref_link" ...>` in your popup.html. (cont)

Comment: (cont) Third, you're comparing `tab.url` against the literal string `"undefined"`. You probably meant `undefined` (unquoted). Fourth, never call `chrome.pageAction.hide`. The page action won't be visible unless you've explicitly called `chrome.pageAction.show`. Following this advice, the popup will stay even if your page contains several frames.

Comment: Thank you very much @RobW for the reply. Oops! I accidentally removed the anchor tag as there was a lot of unrelated html content in the popup. I've updated the code. Secondly, I thought the scripts were needed to be added in the popup as well, I've removed them as well. Thirdly, I want to update the popup.htm page through the background script. Using getBackgroundPage, I can successfully update the popup.htm but as soon as I open a new tab, the popup resets to its default values. It's still not working :(

Comment: I am sorry, I had removed that in my extension files but missed updating here. It still is the same. As long as I am on the current window or switch between current opened tabs, it shows the values fine. As I create a new tab, the popup resets to its default html

Comment: You're using only one global variable for all tabs. If you want tab-specific response values, create a dictionary to map tabIDs to results. Or pass the result as an URL-encoded query string to `chrome.pageAction.setPopup` (untested).

Comment: Victory! Got it solved. Thank you so much @RobW for such prompt help. I used localStorage to store my tabIds. Thanks again. Really appreciated.

Comment: One more thing I am a bit confused about. When I try to inspect my opened popup, the chrome inspector stops working, I have to press escape to close it. What I guess is that the popup is looping, could you find anything like that?

Comment: That's a bug, use right-click on the icon, and choose Inspect popup. The popup and devtools will simultaneously open.

Comment: It works fine this way. So, it means it's not a bug, right?

Comment: It's a bug in the integration of the developer tools <> extension popup. A final request: Could you adjust tour question to Stack Overflow's Q&A format? That is: Put the problem description and question in the question, and post the final solution as an answer. Do not forget to put a checkmark before your answer to show that the question has been solved. For more information, please read the [faq].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using single variable to display the result on the popup. Using localStorage (for storing tabIds and other values for each tab) solved my problem.

**Update:** I am now using window object instead of localStorage, to prevent loading of old data on new browser window.

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version" : 2,

    "name" : "Know your cashback for a site!",
    "version" : "1.0",
    "description" : "Find out about the cashback of the visiting website right in your browser",

    "background" : { "scripts" : ["jquery.js","records.js"]},
    "permissions" : [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "tabs" ],    

    "page_action" : {
                    "default_icon"  : "images/icon.png"
                    }
}
```

records.js

```
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (tab.url !== undefined && changeInfo.status == "complete") {
            $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/chrome_extension/index.php',
            data: "url=" + encodeURIComponent(tab.url),
            type:'GET',
            success: function(resp) {
                    if(resp=="not_found"||resp=="invalid_request") {
                        // do nothing                       
                    } else {
                        resp = JSON.parse(resp);
                        chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
                        chrome.pageAction.setTitle({
                                                   tabId: tabId,
                                                   title: resp.cashback
                                                   });
                        chrome.pageAction.setPopup({
                                                   tabId: tabId,
                                                   popup: "popup.htm"
                                                   });
                    window.window["tab" + tabId] = resp.cashback;
                    window.window["store" + tabId] = resp.store;                
                    }               
                }
            });
    }
};

// Listen for any changes to the URL of any tab.
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);
```

popup.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<span id="request"></span>
<a href="#" id="ref_link"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
var BGPage = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    if(typeof BGPage.window["tab" + tab.id] != undefined) {
            document.getElementById('request').innerHTML = BGPage.window["tab" + tab.id];
            document.getElementById('ref_link').href = BGPage.window["store" + tab.id];     
    }
});
```

Special Thanks to @RobW

Comment: You should not store the tab ids in localStorage, but a global object. LocalStorage persists across browser reloads, while tab ids are unique per session.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Is this OK now? I've used the window object to make my dynamic variables.

Comment: `window.window` is identical to `window`: Both refer to the global object. Now, you're defining a global variables for each tab. It's a better practice to create a dedicated dictionary. For example: `var tabStore = {};` or `window.tabStore = {};` and save results in this object instead: `tabStore[tabId] = resp;`

Comment: Sorry I am a little busy these days, that's why I couldn't reply. I will work on it, and will then let you know. Thank you!